# Eclipse Helios, run server after ant build has successfully finished

Tags: eclipse, ant, jboss, run-configuration

I'm not an Eclipse expert, but here is what I need to do and I hope for your help guys. I have an ant build file in my project. I'd like to have such run configuration where whenever I press the launch button my ant build script is run and if it finished successfully then it starts the already registered in Eclipse Jboss 4.2 server. Would appreciate any comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ant execute task which would start the server by pointing it to your server startup script.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Cheers!!!